# Parsing values from a column while excluding certain values from other column

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have two columns of values of which the second includes a subset of the first. I'm parsing partial matches from the first column with:

```
=query(A:A, "select A where A ends with 'x'")
```

It works fine. How would you modify it in order to exclude the shared values?

Here's an example:

[image: example]

A is where we're parsing from, B is the subset we want to discard, C would be the desired result:

1. filter values to exclude common values with column B
2. return only values ending in 'x'

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask]. Also include in your question what did you already researched and tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

To solve this, you first may need to exclude values from column B, then query result to match only pattern '%x'. Try this formula:

`=QUERY(FILTER(A:A,REGEXMATCH(A:A,JOIN("|",FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")))=false),
"select Col1 where Col1 like '%x'")`

**Edit #2**

[Special symbols](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) for regular expressions are `\ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

If such symbols are met in your data, you need to escape them by `\` in order to use regular expressions. So formula `REGEXMATCH` in this case won't work properly if column B contains special symbols. Possible solution is to replace them like this: `[symbol]` → `[\symbol]`. For example, to replece `()`:

`=REGEXREPLACE(text ;"(\(|\)|\*)";"\\$1")`

Try using this formula in column C to get the result:

`=QUERY(FILTER(A:A,REGEXMATCH(A:A, 
REGEXREPLACE( JOIN("|",FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""));"(\(|\)|\*)";"\\$1"))=false),
"select Col1 where Col1 like '%x'")`

**Original answer**

may be using `not` keyword will work:

```
=query(A:A, "select A where not A ends with 'x'")
```

the same as:

```
=query(A:A, "select A where not A like '%x'")
```

Comment: Perhaps i didnt made myself clear, I've edited the OP for more clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get why numbers 250 and 253 are in column to exclude. And why number 104 is not in the desired result.

Comment: Have a look at the query I'm using, we only want the strings with suffix "x" from the colA so 104 is out. ColB includes a subset of colA (in the example just 102x) but it also includes other values. Perhaps this doesnt affect the solution but then again I'm a noob so I've included them in the example just in case!

Comment: I've updated the answer, guess, now I understand it right.

Comment: Max you're awesome! This works fine though I still  have a slight problem, it seems that REGEXMATCH doesnt like it if the values contains parentheses (eg: 102(x) ) then it tends to disregard any duplicate found in ColB. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Your case is harder, then I thougth. I've updated the answer again. Please, try now.

Comment: Nothing too hard for you it seems... Works like a charm, thank you sir and have a good day!